# How to dynamically add children to a dynamically created EmbeddedViewRef?

Tags: angular

I am trying to create a component dynamically from a template and this component should contain other components created dynamically as well; in other words: I want to create a parent component dynamically and then I want to insert a child or multiple children into this newly created parent. The resulting HTML could look like, for example:

```
<div componentGroupDirective>
   <div myButtonDirective...>... </div>
   <div myButtonDirective...>... </div>
</div>
```

But I don't know how to call createEmbeddedView from the newly created component - or how something like this is done in general. Any ideas? Not working sample code that sketches the idea:

Component HTML

```
<ng-container #container></ng-container>

<ng-template #componentGroupRef let-data>
    <div myComponentGroupDirective></div>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #myButtondRef let-data>
    <button myButtonDirective [someProp]="data.someProp">{{ data.labelProp }} </button>
</ng-template>
```

Component Code

```
@ViewChild('container', { read: ViewContainerRef, static: true })
protected container!: ViewContainerRef;

@ViewChild('componentGroupRef', { read: TemplateRef })
protected componentGroupRef!: TemplateRef<any>;

@ViewChild('myButtondRef', { read: TemplateRef })
protected myButtondRef!: TemplateRef<any>;

const componentGroup = this.componentGroupRef.createEmbeddedView({});
const insertedComponentGroup = this.container.insert(componentGroup);

const buttonViewRef = this.insertedComponentGroup.createEmbeddedView({ $implicit: data });
```

It is somehow working with

```
this.renderer.appendChild(componentGroup.rootNodes[0], buttonViewRef.rootNodes[0]);
```

but then I am not able to pass any context data, so all buttons are just little empty squares ...

Comment: you could call createEmbeddedView on viewContainerRef. it is just easier, why not to do it?

Comment: If I do that, all components will be created on one level, the level of the viewContainerRef. But I want to have something like
<componentGroup>
   <div myButtonDirective...> </div>
   <div myButtonDirective...> </div>
</componentGroup>

The buttons should be the children of the also dynamically created componentGroup.